# Html noobs layouting

Tags: html

How can I make these 3 elements (span, input, input) appear in the same line? as it is now, the span takes left column and 2 rows and the 2 inputs takes the right column one beneath the other

```
           <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">www</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Url" ng-model="currentUrl"/>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Go" ng-click="getUrl()" />
            </div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe: http://jsbin.com/fibofocaya/1/

Comment: @Quentin you can if you include bootstrap http://www.bootply.com/yj7eapiPmY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap, you need to use the `.input-group-button` class...

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/jeuVbS34Zn)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">www</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Url" ng-model="currentUrl">

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Go" ng-click="getUrl()">
  </span>
</div>
```

[The docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

Answer (score -1):

simply add the following css

```
span{
width:200px;
float:left;

}

input{
width:300px;
float:left;
}
```